# "I'm sure I can do it" or "I'm sure THAT I can do it"?

Tags: phrases

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of “that” in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/use-of-that-in-a-sentence)

It's all in the title. Should I use "that" as a connector, or should I refrain from using it ?

Comment: Dupe of [“Use of 'that' in a sentence”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/use-of-that-in-a-sentence), though Stefano can't be blamed, because the site search still doesn't work. I had to hunt for the dupe by googling.