# When is "that" superfluous?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of “that” in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/use-of-that-in-a-sentence)

What are some of the rules surrounding the word "that" and its inclusion or omission in a sentence? For example, "My boss mentioned that you needed help," vs. "My boss mentioned you needed help." Is either form more correct?

Sorry if this seems rudimentary, but I've always felt a little self-conscious about my own usage of this word due to some fuzzy but persistent high school English class memories.