# When can you leave off 'that' in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of “that” in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/use-of-that-in-a-sentence)

Some times I find myself leaving out the 'that' that binds two parts of a sentence together, because it reads 'smoother'. Here's an example:

> I'm at that point towards the end of a book, where you suddenly realize you're reading part two of a trilogy and too much of the plot is left for a satisfactory resolution.

I chose to not say '...suddenly realize *that* you're reading...'. Is this still correct? Is it merely a more informal tone? Bad style?

Side question: What am I actually talking about in grammatical terms? Binding two sentence clauses together with ’that'? What kind of word is 'that' here?