# Relative pronouns, "that" or "who", for type of person

Tags: word-choice, pronouns

A non-native speaker is asking ...

Which should you use, 'which' or 'that,' in the following statement? Since this is mainly talking about the types of persons (within 'her'), you might use 'that,' but would you also use 'who'?

> Sam was praising the industrious worker ***who/that*** she was when she was in the office, not the lazy housewife ***who/that*** she was when she was at home.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use: who/that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/how-to-use-who-that).

Comment: @RegDwight: I'm sure this addresses a different question to the one answered in your link, which only covers cases where *one of* "who" and "that" needs to be present. In this case I think *neither* should be, so it's a different context entirely.

Answer (score 3):

"That" sounds better to my native English ears, but what I would opt for is no "who" or "that" at all.

> Sam was praising the industrious worker she was when she was in the office, not the lazy housewife she was when she was at home.

Edit: to make use of a commenter's astute observation, removing the unnecessary and clunky "when she was", the more fluent sentence would run as follows:

> Sam was praising the industrious worker she was in the office, not the lazy housewife she was at home.

Comment: Thanks, drm65. Would 'who' sound unnatural?

Comment: @Sssamy: I agree with drm65 that "who" sounds a little bit awkward. I can't quite put my finger on why, but using "that" (or nothing at all, as drm65 suggests) definitely sounds better.

Comment: @Sssamy Yes.  "Who" is never used in such a context, that I've ever heard.

Comment: Weird. There's no doubt in my mind that 'who' doesn't work here. And 'that' appears to be at the very least superfluous. I think it's to do with the grammatical role played by 'that' here - *introducing further details about the already-identified industrious worker*, rather than *identifying which particular industrious worker is being spoken of*. I don't know how to make that distinction more precisely.

Comment: This seems MUCH less awkward to me: `Sam was praising the industrious worker she was in the office, not the lazy housewife she was at home.`

Comment: @drm65: I think the reference is to the "job" of _industrious worker_ or _lazy housewife_, rather than the person of _her_, so we have to use "that".  Perhaps.  Certainly _that_ has the flexibility to cope, as witness [Tragicomic's answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/how-to-use-who-that/11339#11339)

Comment: @Rhodri: Nah. The reason *who* doesn't work relates to the sentence structure, not the particular types of person she's being described as.

Comment: ...it's to do with the fact that whether it's *who*, *that*, or nothing at all it comes in the middle of a complete 'identifying noun phrase'. That's not at all the same thing as using *who/that* to introduce a subordinate identifying phrase, where you *have* to use one or the other. As per my comment to @RegDwight against the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

I already upvoted drm65's answer, but I think I'm going to go out on a limb and say that the *only* reasonable form is to use *neither at all*.

It just so happens that because the sentence structure is relatively complex, we can be bamboozled into accepting a superfluous **that** (though probably never a **who**). Try simplifying it a bit...

**Sam liked the whore** [that?] **she was in the bedroom, not the cook** [[that?] she was] **in the kitchen.**

Few would like that **that**, though it is grammatically valid. *Very* few would accept **who**. See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17143/can-who-as-a-relative-pronoun-sometimes-be-omitted) related question.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with *that* here, as well (although I agree that nothing is slightly better). Definitely not *who*, though.

Comment: @Peter Shor: I guess that makes you one of the few! Seriously, I think I really meant (and should have said) *Few would like 'that' better than nothing*.

Comment: Sorry, but if you're going to claim that the only correct form is neither, I'm going to vigorously disagree.  You get neither only by ellipsis from _that_.

Comment: @Rhodri: Well of course I agree I'm eliding **that**. It's no secret - I wrote it in to prove the point. My example sentence is structurally identical to OP's, only simplified to clarify the issue. Are you going to say you'd prefer **who** in mine? Or that you think it's better if I *do* include **that**?

Comment: I'm saying that "the _only_ correct form" is an incorrect statement.

Comment: @Rhodri: oic. Well I may have overstated the case a bit, I agree. I think **who** is downright *wrong*. But **that** is acceptable - it's just that I think nothing at all is best. I'll edit my answer to tone it down a bit.

Comment: @Fumble: righty-ho, I've taken off my -1.  I still disagree with you, and am one of the proud few who would write _that_ and only afterwards consider if I wanted to elide it :-)

Comment: @Rhodri let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/722/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-rhodri)

Comment: I do prefer it without *that* but I'd also prefer to leave the second *she was*, even if that is superfluous, using fewer words isn't always better.

Comment: @z7sg: So do I. I just didn't really feel I could convey that properly by writing **[[that?] she was]**. But what the hell! Here goes!

Comment: @Nohat: I don't really understand why you changed my *whore/bedroom* to *manager/boardroom*. Apart from anything else, it ruins the *cook/kitchen* part. I accept not everyone will be familiar with the *maid/living room, cook/kitchen, whore/bedroom* 'witticism', but many will be. Are you implying my version lowers the tone of the site? Anyway, I don't want to get involved in a slanging match; I just don't understand the rationale.

Answer (score -3):

The answer to this is "who." Use "who" for people, "that" for inanimate objects or nouns and proper nouns.

This is an area of slight contention. Fowler, Gowers and others argue forcefully for "who" in this type of instance, others maintain that a human referent can take "that," so do be mindful of the debate.

Careful writers, expert users and editors will prefer "who" with respect to individuals.

Comment: Gotta disagree. Your **who/that** distinction applies to usages where you *must* use one or the other. In this case you don't actually *need* either, and I agree with @drm65 that 'neither' is the best choice.