# A Question On Relative Pronouns & Conjunctions

Tags: pronouns, conjunctions, quotes, syntactic-analysis

I came across this quote from the movie *RocknRolla*:

> Oh, beauty is a beguiling call to death and I'm addicted to the sweet
>   pitch of its siren. That that starts sweet ends bitter, and that which
>   starts bitter ends sweet.

I understand the metaphor. But I'm confused with the sentence structure of

> That that starts sweet ends bitter, and that which
>   starts bitter ends sweet.

Are the first *that* and the *that* before 'which starts bitter ends sweet' conjunctions while the second *that* and *which* relative pronouns?

Comment: *Beauty* starts by seeming sweet, but ends in bitterness; *death* looks initially uninviting and bitter, but becomes sweetly attractive as the end draws nigh. But it's "poetry", so you can put your own interpretation on it. My interpretation is the switch from *"that"* to *"which"* in the final clause is clumsy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Great I get it now. Why not put down your explanation in a form of an answer instead of a comment :) ? It's odd to have an answered question considered unanswered.

Comment: Strictly speaking I think the question is off-topic Lit. Crit., so I don't think it should be formally "Answered" anyway. ELU doesn't generally welcome questions concerning interpretation of song lyrics, poetry, etc.

Comment: Oh. I've edited the question a bit. Is it still off-topic?

Comment: I think so, yes. I know we're always asking for "more context" here, but your second sentence can be adequately analysed in isolation, as Alan shows. My comment "answer" is basically Lit. Crit., so it's off-topic; his deals with the syntactic roles of *that/which*, so it's on-topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It seems to me that the edit successfully puts the question on-topic. The fact that the sentence can be analyzed out of context shouldn't mean that adding a little context invalidates the question.  (Or maybe your "I think so, yes" was meant to be "Yes, it's better now.".)

Comment: @Alan Munn: Yes, that was terrible phrasing by me. I meant *"Yes, it's better now."* - particularly in conjunction with your 100% on-topic answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two 'that's are simply demonstrative pronouns.  Each conjunct of your sentence has the same basic structure as:

- *He who hesitates is lost.*

In this sentence, the 'he' is a pronoun, and the 'who' is a relative pronoun. In your second conjunct:

- *That which starts bitter ends sweet.*

'that' is a pronoun, and 'which' is a relative pronoun.

In the first conjunct:

- *That that starts sweet ends bitter.*

the first 'that' is a pronoun.  The second 'that' is traditionally called a relative pronoun, but many linguists (including myself) would say that it is simply the subordinating conjunction (or complementizer) 'that'.

Comment: Professor Munn, would it have been incorrect for the sentence to be worded: "That *which* starts sweet end bitter, and that which starts bitter ends sweet."? Would changing the "that that" to "that which" have changed the meaning?

Comment: No, the two forms are pretty much synonymous.

Comment: *That* and *which* are synonymous/interchangeable in this context, but I still think it's stylistically clunky to switch from one to the other in a sentence that (which?!) is based on semantic **and** structural symmetry.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But that has very little to do with the question, which is about the structure.

Comment: I don't disagree - your answer is focussed on exactly the (revised) question. Actually though, I *am* a little confused - if *'which' is a relative pronoun*, why do you say *'that' is a subordinating conjunction (or complementizer)*? I can't see any different roles being performed by the two words in this context, so how can they justify different (syntactic?) names?

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the comments to this question: [Can "who" as a relative pronoun sometimes be ommitted](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/17143/18250), Aaron gives a link to some linguistic discussion of the issue. On both empirical grounds and parsimony, analyzing 'that' as a complementizer is really the preferred analysis. I think that adding more discussion to my answer here would detract from the main point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree. I have argued the exact same point before, and I didn't find the arguments against it convincing.

Comment: Wow you guys are tough.  A downvote for *mentioning* the received linguistic wisdom on 'that' (even though I mentioned that traditionally it could be called a relative pronoun)?

Comment: Woah! That's not *my* downvote! I'm just asking. Bear in mind I haven't followed your link to the earlier question yet (also that I'm just a layman, not a linguist, so I'll probably end up out of my depth when I do anyway! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can check out a version of the argument in chat, too. http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4057526#4057526

Comment: So, in my simple-minded way, should I assume an underlying *"That **thing** which starts sweet ends bitter"*, where *"thing"* can be replaced by *"that"* - then either that word or *"which"* (but not both) can be deleted? I just *knew* I was going to get out of my depth here! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that's the right idea. But 'thing' can be deleted, and you need either (the second) 'that' or 'which' obligatorily in this context because (as in the linked question) the NP in the relative clause is related to the main subject of the relative clause.