# Grammar: Use of 'that'

Tags: british-english, conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of “that” in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/use-of-that-in-a-sentence)

Which of the following is correct in British English?

1) There are 100 people going to the party, so I expect it will be a good night.

2) There are 100 people going to the party, so I expect **that** it will be a good night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are fine.  English is wonderful like this.

There are 100 people going to the party, so I expect that it will be a good night.

There are 100 people going to the party, so I expect it will be a good night.

There are 100 people going to the party, so I expect a good night.

There are 100 people going, I expect it will be a good night.

100 people are going, I expect a good night.

100 party-goers! I expect a good night.

Party! I expect a good night.

Party! Party! PARTY!

Goodnight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a difference in formality between the two versions?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really speak for British specific English, as I'm American. But, I can say that both of those are generally acceptable in these parts.