# Why is 'that' sometimes optional before dependent clauses?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, that, zero-relative-pronoun

Sometimes, the word 'that' to introduce a dependent clause is optional.  For example, these sentences both make sense with or without 'that':

> Long books [that] religious people like tend to be Bibles.
>
> Water tanks [that] fish need are spacious.

... whereas in these sentences, 'that' is mandatory and the sentence is ungrammatical without it:

> Those **that** are rotten must be thrown away.
>
> Cars **that** break down endanger pedestrians.

I can't quite put my finger on the rule which determines when 'that' must be used.  What is it?

Comment: I noticed right away that in your last two examples, "that" is followed by a verb, which is not the case with the first two.

Comment: Related: [Use of "that" in a sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/use-of-that-in-a-sentence).

Comment: Embedded clause or dependent clause?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In both of the examples in which *that* is optional, the relative pronoun is the **object** of the embedded clause.

> **Long books** [that] religious people like tend to be Bibles. [Religious people like **long books**.]
>
> **Water tanks** [that] fish need are spacious. [Fish need **water tanks**.]

This is also allowed when the relative pronoun is the object of a preposition or another oblique argument of the embedded clause:

> This is the **boat** I escaped in. [I escaped in **this boat**.]

In your other examples, the relative pronoun is the **subject** of the embedded clause:

> **Those** that are rotten must be thrown away. [**Those** are rotten.]
>
> **Cars** that break down endanger pedestrians. [**Cars** break down.]

English only allows you to omit *that* when it has been moved from a non-subject position in the embedded clause, and when it's followed by the subject of the embedded clause. I suspect that the reason for this is the ease of comprehension on the part of the listener. A sentence like *Cars break down endanger pedestrians*, if it were grammatical, would be extremely hard to parse.

Comment: Relative clause "that" can be omitted before the subject of a relative clause.  (It doesn't have to represent the object of the relative clause, though it may -- "This is the boat (that) I escaped in".)

Comment: @GregLee that's an important clarification. I'll updated the answer.

Comment: "Bulldogs bulldogs bulldogs fight fight fight.”