# A case of optional “that”: “check the” vs. “check that the”

Tags: grammar, pronouns, rules

Consider the following use case:

- Please check the username and password are correct.
- Please check *that* the username and password are correct.

In this case, I would say that *that* is required because it feels more natural to me and so the flow is better. However, is the lack of *that* wrong in this case?

The question boils down to: when is *that* optional? See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35586/why-is-that-sometimes-optional-before-dependent-clauses). A quick summary:

- *That* is optional if the pronoun is the object.
- *That* is required if the pronoun is the subject.

I think that we fall into the second case: *that* is required because the relative pronoun is the subject. But I'm not sure if I'm interpreting these rules correctly. Can someone please advise?

Comment: This is a totally different **that** (Check that/zero complementiser Peter is here) (que in French) from the one in the linked thread (The house that/which/zero relative pronoun Jack built) (lequel etc in French).

Comment: There is no relative pronoun in your (first) two examples. You probably ought to remove that *"relative-pronouns"* tag.

Comment: The answer on the linked question actually answers this: "English only allows you to omit *that* when it has been moved from the object position of the embedded clause." Here, what you are checking is {the username and password are correct}. That's the object of *check*, and *that* can be omitted.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't quite understand the statement `moved from the object position of the embedded clause`. If I check something for validity, aren't I checking *that* it is valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I've read online regarding this, the easiest thing for me to determine when to use "that" is *to use it* if everything after "that" can be used as a complete sentence.

> Please check that the light is off.

"The light is off." is a complete sentence. "that" is needed.

> Please check the light.

"The light" is not a sentence. Don't use "that".

> Please check that your username and password are correct.

"Your username and password are correct." is a complete sentence. "that" is needed.

> Please check your username and password.

"Your username and password" is a fragment. "that" is not needed.

Comment: In that way I could have `please check` and `the password and username are correct` as separate parts. Since `the password and user name are correct` can stand alone, `that` isn't required? Or do you mean that since `that` isn't a *conjunction* (of sorts) in this case, `that` is required?

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify, I hope. Ignoring my statement about conjunctions.

Comment: Counterexample: "I think that you're wrong". "You're wrong" is a complete sentence, but "that" is optional.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in the desire to use *that* in your sentence.

A great way to tell if your sentence is correct is to dissect it and see how it sounds. This is a huge help in forming sentences that may sound strange, but are correct.

For example, if we take your sentence and split it into two, we can better see how it is structured.

> "*Please check the username and password are correct.*"

Please check what?

- The username is correct.
- The password is correct.

> "*Please check that the username and password are correct.*"

Please check what?

- That the username is correct.
- That the password is correct.

When splitting the first sentence, the structure changes from the command of "Please check its correctness." to "It is correct." (Can't think of a cleaner explanation here)

---

Here is another example in a different light in case that didn't help clarify some:

> "*She and I buy groceries.*"

Who buys groceries?

- "She buys groceries."
- "I buy groceries."

> "*Her and I buy groceries.*"

Who buys groceries?

- "Her buys groceries." (This is why *Her and I* don't work)
- "I buy groceries."