# Missing Conjunction

Tags: conjunctions

As an ESL learner, I find some English constructions quite odd. The following quote, for example, is missing a conjunction between *the fact* and *I work*.

> "I can't find diapers or milk in the stores for my baby, **despite the fact I work** all day long. We want a better future."

I would write "(...) despite the fact **that** I work."

Why don't native writers use conjunctions more often? Is there a rule (that) I'm missing?

http://www.cbc.ca/news/world/venezuela-referendum-1.4208304?cmp=rss

Comment: It's because that Portuguese doesn’t let you omit *que* where English allows you to omit *that*. See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1095  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/35586

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of tchrist's linked questions, but I want to say that I enjoyed your little joke in the last sentence (the bracketed "that"). Was that intentional?

Comment: The highest voted answer in the proposed duplicate is incorrect. It says "that can almost always be dropped." It can only be dropped if *that* is not the subject of the relative clause. For example, you can drop it in: *This is the house that Jack built.* But you can't drop it in: *This is the maiden that milked the cow with the crumpled horn.*

Comment: On the other hand, that question has some really excellent answers that go into detail about exactly when you can and can't drop it. People should upvote them.

Comment: @PeterShor That's true in formal registers, but not in casual speech. ... And by the way, I have always been annoyed by the linguists' common assertion that relative *that* is omitted; I know of no evidence that the omitted relativizer is in fact *that* rather than some *wh-* word.

Comment: @DogLover Yes. The joke was intentional, but I wasn't 100% sure if it's right. I need to study the rules. Thanks!

Comment: I really feel the sentence would read much smoother without the omission: "despite the fact that I work all day long". Something just seems off to me in this particular context. In other sentences, though, the omission is perfectly acceptable (and often preferred, in fact). Ex: "The laptop I bought works well."

Comment: @AleksanderH: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+fact+that+I%2C+the+fact+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20fact%20that%20I%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20fact%20I%3B%2Cc0) agrees. This is a grammatical *the fact that* (i.e., the word *fact* is inserted because a noun is called for there), and when the word *fact* is inserted for grammatical reasons, it seems to almost always include *that*.

Comment: @AleksandrH Definitely. You can sort of "feel" whether or not to drop the "that".

Comment: Interestingly, inserting *the fact that* because a noun is called for seems to have started in the 19th century. I don't know what people did before that. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+fact+that%2Cfacts+&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20fact%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfacts%3B%2Cc0).