# When do you use 'that' and 'which'

Tags: conjunctions

Explain their differences if you like...

I wanted to ask when it is appropriate to use the conjunction 'that' in a sentence. For example:

- The question I want to ask is...

Or

-The question that I want to ask is...

I can't think of more examples right now. But you get what I'm saying. Why do we sometimes use it and sometimes not use it? When is it correct to use??

Comment: The title of your question doesn't match the body of your question. Where does *which* fit in? Are you actually asking about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is 'that' sometimes optional before dependent clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35586/why-is-that-sometimes-optional-before-dependent-clauses) The word "that" is optional in your sentence. In this context, it is not usually termed a conjunction; it is either called a relative pronoun (according to traditional grammar) or a complementizer (according to modern grammar).