# When to use "that"

Tags: grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use of “that” in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/use-of-that-in-a-sentence)

When do we use the word *that*? For example

> I think **that** I will go to the store.
>
> I think I will go to the store.
>
> I slam on my breaks, then I notice **that** it is just one of those yellow
>   flashing yielding stoplights.
>
> I slam on my breaks, then I notice it is just one of those yellow
>   flashing yielding stoplights.