# Should I add a 'that' to this (provided in the body) sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there rules about using "that" to join two clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

In the sentence below, should there be a 'that' after 'realized'? I was feeling really awkward about the construction here. I have put in the rest for context:

> Someone commenting on an article about adulthood at xyz.com said **that he realized he had made** the 'official' transition to adulthood when as a 20 year old, he boarded his first flight without family or friends. 'I was on a plane headed to a different state, and no one cared', he noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "said [that] he realized [that] he had made" is correct with zero, one, or two "that"s. I like it best with just one "that", with a slight preference for it being in the first position.

Comment: Well good to know all three forms are technically correct, that's where the confusion was coming from .