# Can you overuse the word "that"?

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there rules about using “that” to join two clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

If a sentence makes sense to me without the word "that", I tend not to use it. However, I have recently come across a number of "thats" in colleagues work where I wouldn't use them. When should it be used?

Comment: Please could you give some examples of how you think *that* has been misused?

Comment: Your question has been asked before. Check [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses) for some good answers.

Comment: It is true for all that that that that that that that refers to is not the same that that that that refers to.

Comment: Did you know that that question has been asked?

Answer (score 1):

You can use or omit *that* however you want, until you break any grammatical rules. Both of these are correct:

> Do you think John will be late?

and

> Do you think that John will be late?

This can hardly be called *overusing* the word *that*. In some cases using the word can help disambiguate the sentence or at least make it a lot easier to parse. I cannot think of any concrete examples right now, but I'll be thinking about it in the next hour and I'll come back and edit my answer to add the example when one comes into my mind.