# Which is correct, "Indicates" or "Indicates that"?

Tags: grammar

Which one sounds better?

> "it indicates that the lane is closed" or
>
> "it indicates the lane is closed"

Personally I would go with the first one without thinking, but I am reading a document, where the latter one is used consistently, therefore I started to doubt myself. which side do you pick on this one?

Comment: Duplicate of [Are there rules about using “that” to join two clauses?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This particular *that* (there are several others) is being used to mark and introduce a [tensed complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html) (often called simply a *That*-Complement). Such words are called [Complementizers](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/comps.pdf), like the *for...to* of many infinitive complements.

- *I think **that** [I shall never see a poem lovely as a tree]*.
- *I said  **for** [him **to** ask his mother about it].*

Under certain circumstances complementizers may be deleted. For instance, *for* is not normally used before subjects of infinitives:

- *I told him to ask his mother about it.*
- **I told for him to ask his mother about it.*

and *that* is often dropped before a tensed complement, **if it is clear** that it's a complement. This condition is usually met simply by using the clause as object of an appropriate verb, so *that* is probably dropped more frequently than not -- unless it's needed for rhythmic purposes, as in the first sentence above, which comes from a famous American poem.

However, if the complement is the Subject of a verb instead of its Object, *that* **can't** be dropped, because a subordinate clause at the beginning of a sentence needs to be marked as being subordinate:

- ***That** he came to the party is surprising.*
- **He came to the party is surprising.*

So Christi has it right on. One can leave it in or leave it out, and it means the same, and is equally grammatical, either way. Lots of things in English syntax work like that.

Comment: Right. But you don't say: I said him to do this. Unless you are a kid learning a language.

Comment: Right. That's what _say_ requires. [Every verb has its own rules for complements](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/comps.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

I would say that both are grammatically correct and you should use whichever of the two forms you prefer.