# Use of the word "that" in formal tone, technical writing

Tags: conjunctions, parallelism, complex-sentences, compound-sentences

I need help settling a disagreement.  I have read many posts about the word "that" — probably *too* many, since I have gotten myself confused!  In this first example, there are *two* subordinate clauses, and I believe the first sentence (below) is correct.  Which of these is preferable, and why?

> Marine biologists at the University of Utah examined the louse genes and determined ***that*** their hosts split into three species 5–6 million years ago, and ***that*** these species were all equally abundant before whaling began in the 11th century.

vs:

> Marine biologists at the University of Utah examined the louse genes and determined their hosts split into three species 5–6 million years ago, and these species were all equally abundant before whaling began in the 11th century.

Here's a different example in which I'm again of the opinion that the word "that" is necessary, but once again, I know not why:

> During the winter months (July–October), southern right whales come ***so*** close to the shoreline ***that*** visitors can watch whales from strategically placed hotels.

vs:

> During the winter months (July–October), southern right whales come so close to the shoreline, visitors can watch whales from strategically placed hotels.

***I might also note that we are aiming for a formal (encyclopedic) tone.***  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there rules about using "that" to join two clauses?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In both cases, *that* is the *That*-Complementizer, a marker for a tensed Noun Clause, or [Complement](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/complmnt.html).

In the first case, both *that*'s are proper, since the repetition marks the two tensed complements that are conjoined by *and*, thus avoiding ambiguity, which is always a problem in a clause like this.

In the second case, the construction *so Adj that S/such a NP that S* uses the same complementizer *that* to mark the complement clause.

*That* complementizers can be deleted if they are obvious, as in sentences like

- *She thinks (that) Mary likes him.*
- *I'm so tired (that) I can't sleep.*

but not if they mark a subject complement and come first in a sentence

- *That he arrived late is really his own fault.*
- **He arrived late is really his own fault.*

because the complementizer is needed as a flag to parse the clause.

However, the longer a sentence is, and the more grammatical complexities it has, the more it is usually **not** a good idea for a writer to delete every marker (article, preposition, pronoun, complementizer, etc.) that one can, just because it **is** possible.

Generally there is a function that these markers serve, to clarify a sentence, and one should always be aware that they're **potentially** there, whether one deletes them or not.  Putting them back in is the first thing that a writer should do when a sentence is getting troublesome.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  You not only answered the question, but you also helped me to sharpen my focus as to why I asked the question in the first place!

Comment: In formal, encyclopedic technical writing, my objection is with copy editors who indiscriminately purge poor little "that" from articles, _thus_ _introducing_ _ambiguity_ and making the text _less_ _formal_.

Comment: Kudos on the penultimate sentence of your answer. One, it proved very useful to me in my own writing and was exactly what I was seeking. Two, it's genius: in describing the proper use of the that-complementizer in long and grammatically complex sentences, it is itself a long and grammatically complex sentence that uses the that-complementizer quite properly!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is largely a matter of taste that you prefer the former.

That said, in formal writing especially, including *that* is advisable.  It elucidates the fact that an entire phrase, rather than a single noun, is to be the subject of the preceding verb.  This distinction is usually clear with or without *that* in informal English, and including it may even seem verbose; but in more technical English, with more complex sentences and relationships between phrases, its inclusion helps the reader scan the text.  It's more *precise*.

In the examples you gave though, I can't see a strong preference for one or the other (other than stylistic preferences), as both forms are perfectly unambiguous.

> Marine biologists at the University of Utah examined the louse genes and determined their hosts ...

The meaning is clear even at this point in the sentence, as *their hosts* would not be a noun subject of *determined* in this context.

> During the winter months (July–October), southern right whales come so close to the shoreline, visitors ...

Again, the meaning is clear, because of *so* implies a subordinate phrase to follow.  (So close?  How close?)

Comment: Drive-by downvoter, care to offer an explanation?

Comment: It wasn't me (not registered, so can't up- or downvote), but I'm sure the explanation is something like "You're wrong!", "I disagree!", or "You piss me off!" My last two downvotes included explanations. One was a simple "You're wrong", but the other was "You didn't address the question". For the first, there was a link to a Web page that was, IMHO, inappropriate for the point, but for the second, there was a good explanation and the downvoter was correct -- about that, at least. My mistake in the second case. It's nice to know why one gets downvoted: constructive criticism can help.

Comment: Please see also my comments to @JohnLawler above.  @dbase, I also want to thank you as well, because _precision_ is exactly what I'm after.  To me, when I parse that `"Marine biologists..."` sentence which omits the two "thats", I can't determine with certainty whether `*the biologists determined*` that `"these species were equally abundant"`, or whether the author is introducing his (or someone else's) original idea.

Comment: Here's another example.  Would you omit "that" from the following sentence?  `"Recognizing **that** this toll could tip the delicately balanced species towards extinction, NOAA introduced the Atlantic Large Whale Take Reduction Plan in July 1997."` Without "that", is it the recognition _itself_ which jeopardizes the species?

Comment: @grolltech that's a really good example.

Answer (score 0):

First off, in your first example, you are using the word "that" as a conjunction. This means everything before and after that word is an independent clause or a complete sentence. In most cases, it's best to leave the word "that" for safety, but it is up to you to decide if you want to use it. I suggest you leave it.

Answer (score 0):

Words which can be taken in two alternative ways such as "recognizing" in the above example, sometimes need the word "that" in order to prevent the reader from momentarily having to mentally halt to resolve the ambiguity. For instance, one can be recognized for his or her accomplishments or a fact can be recognized (its credence admitted) such as "this toll could tip..."  If I were the writer in the above example, I would tend to include the "that" before "this toll" to avoid even the—admittedly—remote chance of the reader stumbling in that moment.