# Necessity of "that" as a conjunction

Tags: grammar, word-usage, conjunctions

A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20%22that%22#q=define%20%22that%22) reveals that the word `that` can be used in many ways: as a pronoun, determiner, adverb and conjunction. I'm wondering about its usage *specifically* as a conjunction.

Take the following two examples:

> I think that I know who sings this song

and

> I think I know who sings this song

From a colloquial standpoint, I would use the shorter version (the latter).

However, what is the *grammatically-correct* form? Is the word `that`, when used as a **conjunction**, necessary from a grammatical standpoint? It seems superfluous to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This "*that*" is **not** a conjunction;
it is a ***[Complementizer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80683/15299)***.
It introduces tensed clauses.

Tensed clauses of several kinds, in fact:

- [tensed Subject and Object complement clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/370/Complementslide.pdf) (whence the name *complementizer*),
  and
- [restrictive relative clauses](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html), where it may be used instead of a *Wh*-word.

In both cases, *that* may be deleted if it's not needed for clarity.
(there are several contexts where *that* may **not** be deleted, however; it's not totally optional)

Comment: Ah ha! I didn't know how to search for this kind of information - (relatively) obscure grammar concepts are hard to find through Googling... further reading can be done [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer#Empty_complementizers); that page would have answered my question before it needed to be asked! Your other answer was also very helpful (unfortunately it didn't turn up when I searched English.SE). Wikipedia also says that complementizers are [special subordinating *conjunctions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_%28grammar%29#Subordinating_conjunctions). Any thoughts?

Comment: Total nonsense from people who hafta have some way to jam them into the Classical Eight Parts Of Speech somehow.

Comment: Haha, I see. Well, that's good to know! There is a reason why there's 'Wikipedia general' and 'Stack Exchange specific' (in my eyes). Sometimes Wikipedia just doesn't cut it! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure SE cuts it, either. As you point out, it's hard to find that information here, too, if you're not looking for it and nobody points you in that direction. Plenty of people will be happy to give you their opinions on it, though.

Comment: Very good point. Fortunately, I haven't run into any corner-cases like that on any SE site. I may just be a statistical anomaly though, that happens sometimes!

Comment: The SE model is not a good fit with popular knowledge of the English language, which is generally poor, especially among native speakers.

Comment: @automaton: "**Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?**" No, thank you, I wouldn't. I don't like the chat facilities here.

Comment: John, I agree. Knowledge of languages is one of the hardest things (in my experience) to find. I feel silly asking questions about English grammar, considering that my understanding of French grammar is much better. That said, I find both English.SE and French.SE *very* useful, even if the things discussed on the sites are not generally known by either party. Grammar fascinates me, so English/French.SE are my favorite sites to frequent :)

Answer (score -1):

There are definitely times when 'that' as a conjunction is necessary. One example would be with certain verb forms *"I have heard he is dead."* vs *"I have heard that he is dead."*

Another case might be when the subordinate clause marked by the 'that' comes before the main verb *"That he was there, is certain, why he was there, unknown."*

That is used as a conjunction in some cases when you are relating one clause to another: *"He another a whole bowl of Ice Cream, after that he was full."*

The OED gives another interesting example when using 'that' as a conjunction in a periphrastic: *"It was because he failed to prove this that his case broke down."*

Ultimately, that using the word 'that' as a conjunction is often superfluous cannot be denied, that much is sure. However, there are still many cases when it is definitely necessary.

Comment: 'I have heard he is dead' may be used. 'I have heard you snore' may well have a different intended meaning from 'I have heard that you snore'.

Comment: In your example ***...after that he was full*** the word ***that*** is a *pronoun* (not a subordinator/complementizer/ conjunction).

Comment: Strange,  for some reason the OED listed that usage under the conjunction form of "that" but your explanation makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Because the first one is read not as the second one with an omitted "that", but as a different construction that is more like the Latin AcI. You see that when you put it in the third person: "I have heard that he snores" (that-clause), "I have heard he snores" (the same with omitted "that"), "I have heard him snore" (AcI).