# parts of speech the word 'that' can belong to

Tags: parts-of-speech, that

Is the THAT in the following sentence a conjunction?

> There is strong evidence that Zika is spreading fast all over Brazil.

Comment: It's not really *anything*, as can be shown by the fact that it can be deleted with no loss of clarity. But according to [this site](http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-that/), if you insist on classing your particular example as one of *definite article, pronoun, adverb, adjective, conjunction*, it'll be the last one of those.

Comment: It's a subordinator (or subordinating conjunction) introducing the subordinate clause _that Zika is spreading fast all over Brazil_ which is functioning as complement to "evidence".

Answer (score 1):

*That* can be the distal demonstrative determiner (contrasting with *this*, the proximal demonstrative determiner); it precedes noun phrases, and can act as a pronoun -- yes, I mean ***that*** (one).

*That* can also be a [complementizer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111125/15299) for tensed clauses of all sorts.
It appears in restrictive relative clauses where *wh*-words aren't used.
Relative clauses are adjective clauses; they modify nouns.

- *I met the man who/that came to dinner.*

*That* also used to appear in adverb clauses, after the introductory conjunction, as in *before **that** we set up the tent* in the audio [that's linked here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNxLxTZHKM8). But that *that* [occurs only in a few dialects](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73368/15299) nowadays.

Finally, the *that*-clause in the example sentence (*There is strong evidence that Zika is spreading fast all over Brazil*) is a complement clause modifying *evidence*. [Complement clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80683/15299), which include *that*-clauses as one subtype, usually are subjects or objects of predicates, but in the example sentence it's a noun complement clause, a structure where a complement clause modifies a noun.  This is only possible with a [picture noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/113916/15299) like *evidence*.

Comment: I agree that it's a complement clause (though I prefer the label 'content clause'), but its function is that of complement, not modifier, as is evident from the fact that it has to be licensed by "evidence". I think it's important to distinguish the functions of complement and modifier.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, 'that' is a subordinating conjunction.  The copula in '.. is spreading ..' is weakened from being stated as a fact, but it is linked to the other copula '.. is strong evidence'.