# Demonstrative Pronouns

Tags: pronouns, demonstratives

I understand that a demonstrative pronoun is a word that **replaces** a noun as if pointing to it. For example, "I want to buy a car. **This** one is cheap. **Those** are expensive." This and those are demonstrative pronouns, they replace the noun car. But, if I say, "This car is expensive," what role does **this** play now? Is it still a demonstrative pronoun? Now the sentence has a noun **and** a pronoun? Or is 'this' now a different part of speech? Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: *I want to buy a car. This **one** is cheap. Those **cars** are expensive*. [The same words (**demonstrative pronouns**) are used as **demonstrative adjectives** when they modify nouns or pronouns.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/demonstrative-pronouns#:~:text=Pronouns%20that%20point%20to%20specific,%2C%E2%80%9D%20%E2%80%9Cthose%20boys.%E2%80%9D)

Comment: The demonstratives are not pronouns; they are **determinatives**. In their dependent use, as in "This one is cheap", they function as pre-head determiner. In their independent use, as in "those are expensive" they function as 'fused' determiner-head in NP structure.

Comment: Think of demonstratives as special-purpose pronouns that can work like adjectives or nouns: _this, this one, this car, this old red car with paint stains_. Being a determiner, it has to go in the noun phrase before all the adjectives, like articles. In fact, _this, that, these, those_ and _the_ have a historic root in common.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parts of speech the word 'that' can belong to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309031/parts-of-speech-the-word-that-can-belong-to)

Comment: The demonstratives can't be pronouns because they have plural forms, and unlike pronouns they can function as degree modifier, as in "Ed is not often **this** late".

Comment: Thank you for the input everyone. This is all very helpful. I've got what I need now.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I believe it's the same pronoun in both cases. Wether it's "this" or "this car".

They take the subject role in all your examples.
In case of "this" we are just omitting the noun "car" to avoid duplicate words.

Comment: That's incorrect. In their dependent use, as in "This one is cheap", they function as pre-head determiner. In their independent use, as in "those are expensive" they function as 'fused' determiner-head in NP structure.

Comment: That's CGEL terminology, and correct as far as it goes. As long as you don't limit _pronoun_ to independent NPs, though, there's no harm in calling demonstratives pronouns. It's easier to stretch one's concept of what a "pronoun" is than it is to memorize a dozen novel terms, however exact they may be, if they're not understood. That's what brought us to this pass in the first place.

Comment: Which is, of course, the grammar that many of us are using. The demonstratives can't be pronouns because they have plural forms, and unlike pronouns they can function as degree modifier, as in "Ed is not often **this** late".

Answer (score -1):

In "This car is expensive," **this** is a determiner acting as demonstrative adjective.