# So hard "that" I can't tell the difference

Tags: word-usage

I have always been doubtful about whether  I have to put " THAT"  when I want to give an explanation or reason for something happening or not.

" I'm so tired I can't even stand up"  or "I'm so tired THat I can't even stand up"

His  biggest problem at the interview was he didn't know to read.

His  biggest problem at the interview was THAT he didn't know to read.

My only problem was I needed money I didn't have

My only problem was THAT I needed money I didn't have.

This is so disappointing I don't even wan to say a word about it.

This is so disappointing THAT I don't even want to say a word about it.

I know I can leave out "That" when another  subject goes immediately after the first verb, but when I'm trying to explain the reason for something happening, I find THAT useful. Is that correct grammar?

Comment: My understanding is you might need a comma in place of THAT, in order for it to be correct grammar. If someone could confirm that'd be great.

Comment: Take a look at John Lawler's answer in this [ELU Q&A](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80680/use-of-the-word-that-in-formal-tone-technical-writing).

Comment: If for translation or for non-native readers, the word 'that' adds to the clarity, even though we easily fill it in.

Comment: I have for about 18 months been deliberately omitting *that* in almost everything I've written and not one person has ever tried to correct me…