# What is the subject in the relative clause “that it affects the Earth's balance"?

Tags: relative-clauses, that

> People have extracted so much underground water that it affects the Earth's balance.

Most relative clauses start with a relative pronoun, such as "that."
What is the subject in the relative clause above? Is it "that" or "it?"

Comment: There's no relative clause in that sentence. There's a content clause licensed by _so_.

Comment: So not all clauses start with "that " is consider relative clause?

Comment: @MuuuMu Certainly not! :) *that* is a marker that tells you that the following clause is a subordinate, declarative  one. I occurs often after verbs like *like, think, say, recommend, know* etc. In the sentence above the clause *that it affects the Earth's balance* is a complement of the adverb *so.* It tells us how much *so much* really was.

Comment: The (understood) referent of 'semi-referential' 'it' is 'the relocation, in extraction processes, of a [very considerable] mass of water'. // This 'that' is the complementiser (French 'qui/que'), not the pronoun/determiner (French 'ça/cet ...'), and is never a subject.

Comment: The "that" is a **subordinator** functioning as a **marker** of subordination.

Comment: ... in some grammars.

Comment: Note that 'People have extracted so much underground water that it affects the Earth's balance' is essentially a variant of 'People have extracted so much underground water that the Earth's balance is affected'. Especially with heavyweight subjects, strategies to push them further back in the sentence are often used. This sentence uses 'dummy [I'd say semi-referential, as explained above] _it_'.

Comment: The word "that" is not being used here as a relative pronoun at all; it's being used as a conjunction.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a relative clause, even if it does start with *that*. There are better ways to identify relatives.

The clause

- *that it affects the Earth's balance*

is a complement clause that's part of the [*so `Adj`/such `NP` that `S`* construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80683/15299).

This construction has two parts

1. Either ***so*** before adjectives, or ***such*** before noun phrases:
   *So long, so firm, so fully-packed, so free and easy on the draw*
   *Such a nice dog, such a lovely day, such an awful smell*
2. Followed by a tensed *that*-clause complement to the entire of Part 1,
   expressing the result of the degree of the adjective or noun properties discussed:
   *This hotdog is so long (that) it flops out the end of the bun.*
   *This is such a long hotdog (that) it flops out the end of the bun.*
   *She drank so much water (that) she had to run for the bathroom.*

Oh, and the subject of *that it affects the Earth's balance* is *it*, a non-relative pronoun that's coreferential with the clause *People have extracted so much underground water.*

Comment: Also *so determiner* and *so adverb*, of course. And even *so verb/VP*:  "He so wanted to be loved by his dad that he'd spent his life emulating his father's version of success."

Comment: Adverbs are functionally identical to adjectives in most constructions. What's an example of _so_ + Det?

Comment: Theoretically *so few*, *so many*, *so little* and perhaps *so much*. Paucal or multal quantifiers, essentially.

Comment: Thanks. That's why "adverb" is such a useless term; of course they were marked in Latin, so ...

Answer (score 6):

> *People have extracted so much underground water* [*that it affects the*
> *Earth's balance*].

As DW256 says, the bracketed element is not a relative clause but a declarative content clause. Its function is that of 'indirect **complement**' in clause structure, where it has a resultative meaning. Its subject is "**it**"

It's called indirect because although it follows the head noun, it is not the head noun that licenses it but the "so" that modifies "much".

Answer (score -1):

There could be two scenarios. Make it a sentence with a relative clause (like the picture) or omit "that" make two independent clauses.

[image: image of sentence structure]