# Is "that" required in "It turns out that he has requested"?

Tags: conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there rules about using “that” to join two clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

Should I use the word *that* or not in following sentence?

> It turns out *that* he has requested review from reviewers on the advancement of two year in XYZ organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extract from ‘An A-Z of English Grammar and Usage’ by Geoffrey Leech and others explains when *that* can be omitted when it introduces a dependent *that*-clause. (Other considerations apply when *that* introduces a defining relative clause):

> We can omit **that** in all positions, except when the **that** goes
>   at the beginning of the sentence or when the **that**- clause comes
>   after an abstract noun. We usually omit **that** in speech.

It follows that you can omit *that* in your example. However, if you are ever in any doubt about omitting it, particularly in a very formal context, it is safer to include it.

(You do, however, need *a* before *review* and an *s* at the end of *year*. In fact, the whole sentence looks as if it needs to be rewritten.)

Comment: That answer makes a lot of sense. +1