# I am confused about the use of “that they” in English. When should we use “that”?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Are there rules about using “that” to join two clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

> I have seen the car that they bought.
>
> There is more than one option that they can take.

Which is correct?

Comment: Both examples are correct; both would be correct without the "that". But there are many questions about that on this site; yours is a duplicate.

Comment: In this case "that" is synonymous with "which".

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples are grammatical. However, *that* may be omitted from this kind of relative clause when, as in your examples, it is the object.

(You will see that I have edited the title of your question. It’s important to learn the difference between the present participle (*confusing*) and the past participle (*confused*).