# What is the difference between "compound" and "complex" sentences?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, conjunction-reduction

And what is the difference between coordinating and subordinating conjunctions? Is one kind of sentence (compound or complex) characterized by either a coordinating or subordinating conjunction, while the other kind is characterized by the other?

Comment: This might be a good place to ask, but I'm having trouble understanding what you are asking. Do you think you can make your question clearer?

Comment: @KitFox: Are coordinating/subordinating conjunctions used in compound/complex sentences or clauses? Do I have my terms "backward?" Examples? Sorry for the "matrix" format of this question but I think in those terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is a good place. It's simple, really.

There are two ways to combine clauses. One of them is simply stacking together sentences, like

- *He went to the store **and** he bought some bread **and** he drove home **but** he left it in the car.*

This is a compound sentence (not "compound clause", by the way); it contains only clauses that are linked together by the coordinating conjunctions ***and, or,*** and ***but***. Compound sentences can be reduced by [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299), producing, for instance

- *He went to the store **and** bought some bread **and** drove home **but** left it in the car.*

Compound sentences are easy; all the sentences are on the same level as main clauses, and none of them modify another clause.

Complex sentences — the other way to combine clauses — are **not** easy. A complex sentence has at least one subordinate clause, and there are [a **lot** of different kinds](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111125/15299) of subordinate clause, each with their own set of rules and their own set of idioms and connotations.

Comment: OK, it seems like my basic idea was right. "Coordinate" =compound, "subordinate = complex, and those are the ways you make sentences out of clauses. The examples were helpful. +1 possibly an acceptance, but I like to wait a day or two for the latter.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. But the names are irrelevant, really. Most sentences are complex sentences, and that's what syntax is mostly about.

Answer (score 1):

**COMPOUND SENTENCES:-** 
Having one or more main clauses.

**SIMPLE SENTENCES:-** 
Having a main clause.

**COMPLEX SENTENCES:-** 
Having one main and two or three subordinate clauses.

Comment: use citations in answers please. for example: Search Results
       Dictionary
       com·pound sen·tence
       noun
       plural noun: compound sentences

    a sentence with more than one subject or predicate.                                                              You will need to learn to format and cite you answers.  Tutorials are on this forum.