# Show we care or show that we care

Tags: grammar

The title says it all really... This is one of those value statement things.
'Show we care' is the proposal. It just sounds like lazy English to my ear, I want to say 'Show that we care'

Ignoring the trite nature of the statement, should I care?

Comment: show that you care :D

Comment: Is this really a question?

Comment: [Are there rules about using “that” to join two clauses?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

Answer (score 2):

From Subscription-only LDOCE:

> **That** is often left out when it is the object of the verb in the relative clause:
>
> *They have not kept the promises they made (=that they made).*
>
> That can only be used as a relative pronoun to specify a person or
>   thing, not to add extra information. When adding extra information,
>   use **who** or **which**:
>
> *She had to look after her husband, who was sick.*

You might be right feeling that it sounds like lazy English, however that happens in all languages, not just English, and it can sound more native, since the average native speakers tend to speak the language fast and fluent, and they do happen to skip some words in sentences, rather than forming them word-by-word based on the books (and in this case this is totally grammatical). Therefore, either is just fine, and you can choose to use whichever you like (as long as you follow the rules correctly).