# "Make sure" vs. "Make sure that"

Tags: vocabulary

Is one more correct than  the other?

Make sure the part is connected to the widget.

Make sure that the part is connected to the widget.

Answer (score 1):

No, one is not more correct than the other.

Comment: Right. They are both grammatical. [Complementizer _that_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/111125/15299) may be omitted at the speaker's discretion, unless it (and the clause it introduces) occurs at the beginning of the sentence; then it has to stay. But that's rare, and it's not the case here.