# Is it possible to omit a relative pronoun as subject?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, relative-pronouns, omissibility

When Casals laid eyes on ***cello music he never knew existed***....

I thought the verb '*existed*' belongs to the antecedent, '*cello music*', and '*he never knew*' is just an embedded clause in the sentence. So the sentence could be '*When Casal laid eyes on* *cello music **which/that** he never knew existed*...'. Is that correct?

Here, I need an explanation. I've learned relative pronouns as subject cannot be omitted. If it is right, how is it possible to omit '*which*' or '*that*' in that sentence? Shouldn't I put '*which*' or '*that*' in the sentence? 
If the relative pronoun '*which*' cannot be put between '*cello music*' and *'he never knew existed*', the clause *'he never knew existed'* has two main verbs, which looks like a pretty weird sentence to me...

Please help me figure out how this sentence works. 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there rules about using "that" to join two clauses?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

Comment: @tchrist I know what you're trying to say.. but if there's no missing relative pronoun, could you explain more on that clause, "_he never knew existed_"? Thank you very much.

Comment: The moved/deleted/changed pronoun _that_ (which has been left out of _cello music [that] he never knew existed_), is indeed a subject. It is the subject of _existed_. But the _existed_ clause is not the relative clause; it's the complement clause of _knew_. The verb of the relative clause is _knew_, and the subject of _knew_ is _he_, and the rule says that you can't delete the subject **of the relative clause** -- not that you can't delete something that's a subject in a lower clause.

Comment: @JohnLawler Interesting! Your explanation is very different from what other people said... So the deleted pronoun,_that_ is a subject, but the pronoun is not a relative pronoun as a subject. Is that correct? Then how _that .... existed_ clause acts as a complement clause of _knew_? Can you give me more examples of the divided(I don't know what to call it) clause, like _that....existed_? Can I use_which_ instead of _that_ or only_that_ should be used? I really appreciate your helping me.

Comment: Relative clause formation takes a noun phrase that's coreferential to the noun the clause is modifying (_Bill saw the man. Mary knows the man_) changes it to a relative pronoun and moves it to the front of the clause --> _Bill saw the man that Mary knew_). Relative clause formation can extract a noun phrase from indefinitely far down the clause trail: _the man that Bill said Mary wanted me to get to know better_ extracts _that_ from its original position as the direct object of _know_.  That's an object; here's a subject: _the man that Bill said Mary wanted to plow the driveway_.

Comment: @Araucaria So Araucaria Do you have any other ideas on the sentence? I'm still figuring out how the sentence works...

Comment: @JohnLawler I have one more question to ask you.. Is it _the man that Bill said_ or _the man that Bill saw_ in your example above? At first, I thought it was just a typo. And then I carefully read your comment again thinking that it might not be a typo...If you write _said_  instead of _saw_ , I don't understand what the clause means... Thanks! (I mistakenly deleted my 'thank you' comment! Thanks again!)