# Does this sentence require the addition of the word "that" between "hope" and "the patient"?

Tags: sentence, that

Should the following sentence be altered to say "in the hope THAT the patient would still be alive"?

> He would then have to ride many hours, maybe changing to a fresh horse at some farm, in the hope the patient would still be alive by the time he arrived.

Comment: It's not ungrammatical without it, but it's long and contains many clauses in complex relations, so it's only fair to the reader to include a complementizer here and there to prevent the reader getting lost -- or more likely losing interest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there rules about using "that" to join two clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

Answer (score 1):

Either way, the sentence makes sense. When you give the phrase from the book, the word "that" makes no difference in the meaning of the word. You can go with either one.