# Omitting "that" in a sentence

Tags: grammar, phrases, that

If I were to say, *"I hope that this will work"*, would it also be correct to say, *"I hope this will work"*? Would both be grammatically correct?

Comment: Sometimes "that" marker is obligatory, sometimes optional, sometimes not allowed. There is no one simple general rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there rules about using "that" to join two clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are correct. The word "that" when used to express a wish, feeling, or attitude towards something (i.e., when used in the subjunctive) is often left out, especially in less formal settings.

> "I wish that you wouldn't do that"

is just as acceptable as

> "I wish you wouldn't do that"

Comment: This doesn’t really have anything to do with wishes or subjunctives—in fact, the example in the question is indicative, not subjunctive. _That_ is generally omissible when it’s a complementiser, regardless of what type of subordinate clause it heads.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. In this case 'that' isn't being used demonstratively. Here the object of this sentence is a 'that-clause', where 'that' helps connect the (in this case transitive) verb with its object, "you wouldn't do that". If the sentence was much longer then using 'that' would help indicate the object.