# What is the grammatical role of *your* in "... by your being ..." phrases?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-case, gerund-phrases

While writing a sentence the other day, it struck me that the following phrase has an odd feel to it that I cannot explain:

- *Everyone will benefit by your being well cared for.*

I kept wanting to use *you're* but I knew that wasn't right yet somehow the word *your* in this context feels sort-of possessive (as it should) and at the same time sort of verb-like. I can't explain it any better than that and maybe someone with better grammar chops than I have can help me understand how it fits grammatically in this context.

Another way looking at this might be:
"Why does this usage of *your* seem to create a grammatical dissonance?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subordinate clause

- *your being well cared for*

is the object of the preposition *by*.
That makes it a noun clause, i.e, a clause that acts as a noun.

Here's an elaboration of what I said about noun clauses [in this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111125/15299):

> **Noun** clauses (also called *Complements*) act like nouns, as subject or object. The noun subordinate clauses are boldfaced in the examples below. There are four varieties, each with its own complementizer. Two types are tensed; they must have a subject and a tensed verb. Untensed (non-finite) clause types -- infinitives and gerunds -- often have missing subjects.

> Subject: ***For me to leave early** would be a mistake.* (infinitive "*for-to*" complementizer)
> Subject: ***Leaving early** is not recommended.*   (gerund complementizer, missing subject)

> Subject: ***What he told me** is not for publication.*
> (embedded question tensed complementizer)
> Subject: ***That I have to leave early** is unfortunate.* (*that* tensed complementizer)

> Object: *They told me **to leave early**.*  (infinitive complementizer, missing subject)
> Object: *I hate **his playing the piano at all hours**.*
> (gerund "`POSS`-*ing*" complementizer)

> Object: *I didn't hear **what she told you**.* (embedded question tensed complementizer)
> Object: *They told me **that I had to leave early**.*  (*that* tensed complementizer)

Other names for the infinitive complementizer include "*for-to* complementizer",
because it has two parts:

1. *to* marks the verb phrase of the infinitive clause, while
2. *for* marks the subject, obligatorily in the infinitive subject clause beginning the sentence.
   *For her to win was not unexpected.* ~~~ **Her to win was not unexpected.*

Everybody knows the *to* part; omission of *to* in infinitives like *do* in *let me do it* is unusual.
But the subject is more often deleted than present in infinitive clauses, and even when it is present, it is often seen without *for*. That's infinitives.

The other untensed type is the gerund clause, and once again there are two parts to the complementizer, one marking the subject and one the verb phrase.

1. **Either**
   `POSS` (*Bill's, my, your, the old man's,* etc.)
   **Or**
   `ACC` (*Bill, me, you, the old man,* etc.)
   marks the subject of a gerund, if present. I.e, you get your choice how to mark the subject --
       ***your** being well cared for* and ***you** being well cared for* are **both** grammatical.
2. The first verb in a gerund verb phrase must have the *-ing* verb form.
   The technical names are the "`POSS`-*ing* complementizer" and "the `ACC`-*ing* complementizer".

So, to answer the questions, the grammatical role of *your* is Subject of the gerund clause.
I would guess the dissonance comes from the fact that

- You're being well cared for.

is a grammatical and homophonous assertive main clause that is, however, tensed. So its subject can't be deleted and can't be possessive or accusative. Whereas

- your being well cared for

is not tensed, not a main clause, and is presupposed instead of asserted, so its subject can be anything except a nominative pronoun (*I, we, he, she, they*). That's enough to confuse anybody.

Comment: Wow, now THAT is a great StackExchange-style answer! Thank you.

Comment: In the four pairs of examples under NOUN, first pair and third pair are noun phrases; second and fourth are noun clauses. I tried to get examples of NF clauses and the answers I got were all phrases.  We need to understand that a clause has subject and verb parts, whereas a phrase doesn't have it. Fitting in words with participial, gerunds/verbal nouns and or infinitives will make NF phrases only because they cannot accommodate tenses. Without tenses, how can we standardize it to have subject and verb part?

Answer (score 0):

> your being well cared for.

Here **your** is a possessive determiner qualifying the gerund "being." "Being" is the head of the gerundive phrase "being well cared for."