# What does "John I believe Sally said Bill believed Sue saw" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

What does the sentence:

*"John I believe Sally said Bill believed Sue saw."*

mean?

It is cited in a textbook as an example of a grammatical but uncommon sentence.

Source: Manning, Christopher D., and Hinrich Schütze. *Foundations of statistical natural language processing.* Cambridge: MIT press, 1999. p. 10.

Comment: It probably means you're missing punctuation. "Colourless green ideas sleep furiously" is also grammatical, although it doesn't mean anything logically. It's quite common though, on this website anyway, as it's a famous demonstration of why "grammatical" isn't the be-all and end-all.

Comment: It needs punctuation. _John, I believe Sally said Bill believed Sue saw_ [her parents / better after her operation / ...]. The final 'saw' here would be the detransitivised usage ('Nobody saw me do it.' ... 'Jill saw!')

Comment: Or _John – I believe Sally said, Bill – believed Sue saw._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the explanation, but there seems to be a variant without adding any punctuation.

Comment: I'd argue that it's so unidiomatic as to be 'incorrect' anyway, but would accept that the same applies to my suggestions. The 'Buffalo x 8' sentence has probably never been used in earnest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *John I believe Sally said Bill believed Sue saw.*

is a transform of the grammatical (though complex) sentence

- *I believe Sally said Bill believed Sue saw **John**.*

via the [Left Dislocation](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20left%20dislocation) transformation. This sentence in turn is a transform of

- *I believe **that** Sally said **that** Bill believed **that** Sue saw John.*

which is much clearer, though longer, with all three [complementizer *that*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111125/15299)'s.

***Executive Summary:***
   Replace all the stuff that's been deleted **before** you try to parse the sentence.

Comment: I'm tempted to quote the sage who said 'It's grammatical, but that's the only good thing you can say about it.'

Comment: Without thinking of such a 'dislocation', can't it be *John, I believe **what** Sally said, (what) Bill believed, (what) Sue saw?* An example of asyndeton too!

Comment: If you pronounce it differently, with different intonation and stress, it can mean that. But no one would interpret a written sentence that way without some serious punctuation or in a poem.