# Thinks vs. Thinks that

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Which of these is preferable in a formal essay?

> He thinks **that** the King will fall ill.
>
> He thinks the King will fall ill.

This can be extended to other words, like knows, predicts, or concludes. But what troubles me is that there seems to be no accepted answer for all words.

For example, it sounds more natural to write

> He predicts **that** it will rain today.

than without "that".

But it also sounds more natural to write

> He thinks it will rain today.

than with "that".

Comment: It doesn't matter either way, grammatically. I think it's a matter of personal style. I'd be curious to see what other people think of this, though.

Comment: you might want to check out this post: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses

Comment: 'The public considered Bill finished' and 'The public considered that Bill finished' can have very different meanings.