# The "that" elimination problem

Tags: grammaticality, clauses, that, omissibility, predicate-frames

The sentence

1. I marveled that you chuckled that I said "juxtaposition".

suffers from "that" overload. We'd all agree.

It's easy to slim either 'that'. Hence either

2. I marveled you chuckled that I said "juxtaposition".
3. I marveled that you chuckled I said "juxtaposition".

sounds fine.

Does any rule prevent us from going all the way and discarding both?

4. I marveled you chuckled I said "juxtaposition".

Comment: Near duplicate of [Are there rules about using “that” to join two clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1095/2085)

Comment: The second "that" can easily be replaced. *I marveled that you chuckled when I said "juxtaposition".* In your final version, the sequence of events becomes unclear.

Comment: Actually, the first version sound a hair "creaky", but the other three just sound wrong.

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with you, but your revised sentence means something else. In the original sentence the word uttered itself triggered a response. Your revised sentence suggests that the timing of uttering the word in question is the issue.

Comment: @HotLicks Which one is the first? (Are you counting the original or just the revisions?) I added labels for clarity.

Comment: @tchrist If in the future someone asks something about a triple cascade of "that", you can refer them here. But starting off the cascade cannot (IMHO) be considered a duplication.

Comment: I concur with @HotLicks. I think the problem is that you can't "chuckle that", and you can't very easily "marvel that". Both those verbs need *at*. And once that is established, *at* cannot be omitted.

Comment: I thought you said he hoped they knew we insisted she have mint ice cream before bed.

Comment: @tchrist lol... You got it—my question, that is. In math we're used to add parentheses when necessary and to omit them otherwise. Your sentence is painful because it begs for parentheses for comprehension. Does one get away with just two conjunctions? When?

Comment: @Calaf: I had no trouble parsing Tom's sentence. The thing I did have trouble was your sentence: "In math **we're used to add** parentheses when necessary ..." I think you mean "we're used to **adding**" ...

Comment: _Chuckle_ is not a speech verb. You can _whisper, shout, snap, cackle,_ or _pipe up_ with a direct quotation like "It's 2 pm", or an indirect _that_ clause; but you can't, for example, *_chuckle that it's 2 pm_. You can _chuckle **about**_ something, but not a _that_-complement. One of the ways of getting a _that_-complement is the _the fact that_ construction; you can chuckle about the fact that it's 2 pm. **But** this construction is factive, and commits the speaker to the truth of the _that_-clause, which they may not be able to afford.

Comment: @Robusto This rumor my girlfriend cooks me every recipe a cook her mother knows from TV creates is a total lie!

Comment: @tchrist: I get it, but you're making my head hurt! ^_^

Comment: @Robusto Oh then just add all the implied instances of *that* back in I left out. Funny how this doesn't make it any easier. That's because chained right branching is trivial, and nobody ever gets confused by omitting *that* there. What taxes the mind is  syntactically complex embedding of structures where you have to keep track of pending elements. As you might guess, [the paper I pinched that one from](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2017.02268/full#h7) had had it in German shown.

Comment: To suffer from "that 'overload' " is subjective. Different people interpret style differently. So, it's most likely *not* the case that "we'd all agree."

Comment: That that that that that question refers to is obviously needed!

Comment: @HotLicks Why do you have five 'that's? Your sentence only makes sense (to me) with four (and the second should really be quoted or _italicized_).

Comment: @Calaf - That that that that comment includes is the subject of that that question.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> *Chuckle* is not a speech verb. You can *whisper, shout, snap, cackle,* or *pipe up* with a direct quotation like "It's 2 pm", or an indirect *that* clause; but you can't, for example, **chuckle that it's 2 pm*. You can *chuckle **about*** something, but not a *that*-complement. One of the ways of getting a *that*-complement is the *the fact that* construction; you can chuckle about the fact that it's 2 pm. **But** this construction is factive, and commits the speaker to the truth of the *that*-clause, which they may not be able to afford.