# Which sentence is grammatically correct? This is the email John sent Or This is the email that John sent

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm not sure which one is grammatically correct.
Any input is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

"This is the email John sent
Or
This is the email that John sent"

Comment: They're both correct. _That_ can be dropped from relative clauses if it isn't the subject. Here it's the object of _sent_, so it's optional. You can look this up for yourself, and should.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there rules about using "that" to join two clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)