# relative pronouns "who" and "that" used for people

Tags: grammar

The New York Times of June 15 quoted Biden as saying: “We’re approaching a sad milestone — almost 600,000 lost lives because of Covid-19 in America. My heart goes out to all those (1) who’ve lost a loved one. I know that black hole that seems to consume you, that fills up your chest, when you lose someone (2) that’s close to you (3) that you adored.”
Are the numbered three relative pronouns “who” and “that” interchangeable? Or is there any difference in nuance between them?

Comment: 'Who/who've' is more personal, less clinical than 'that', so grammaticality is not the only driver in play here. I'd certainly prefer 'who've' in (1). However, I'd switch, like Biden, to 'that' in (3) (which really forces the switch in adjacent (2)) to acknowledge the distancing.

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dance_with_the_one_that_brought_you) lists many variants of the proverb, but the page title is *Dance with the one that brought you*

Answer (score 5):

*That* is routinely used as a relative pronoun equivalent to *who* for people or *which* for things and abstractions. There are those who will complain at calling *that* a relative pronoun; they have a point -- it used to be a complementizer like the *that* in

- *I think **that** I shall never see*

The complementizer *that* used to appear in all subordinate clauses, like the *that* in Chaucer's

- *Whan **that** aprille, with his shoures soote*

It sounds strange to say, in modern English, *When that April is over*; what's the *that* for? It still exists, [though, in local dialects](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111125/15299),
In relative clauses, it wasn't necessary to mark the clause as subordinate, so it got re-used (as small pieces of grammar are -- look at all the chunks beginning with *wh* and *th* still around today.)

*That* and *Wh*-words are not completely interchangeable in relative clauses. In restrictive clauses, they are, and you can use *that* anywhere you'd use a *Wh*-word. But only *Wh*-words can be used in **non**-restrictive relatives; that's one way we mark non-restrictive relatives now, along with the comma intonation before (and after, if they're not final).