# "I wish I had", or "I wish THAT I had?"

Tags: grammar

I try to keep my writing as lean and crisp as possible, so I've usually omitted "that" in cases like this, but I'm aware I might be mistaken.  A cursory search through Google didn't yield any answers, so I thought I'd ask...

Should I write:

I wish I had a photograph to share, but I'll leave you this gift instead.

or

I wish that I had a photograph to share, but I'll leave you this gift instead.

Thanks so much for your insight!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there rules about using "that" to join two clauses?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/are-there-rules-about-using-that-to-join-two-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

I wish **that** I had

Is the grammatically correct original form, but since English is very flexible, in most verbal situations the 'that' would be skipped.

"I wish I had" is fine, in both written and oral forms.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).